# ASP.NET Core: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core Windows Worker Service in Visual Studio 2022.
Whenever I build or run the application,
I got this error:

I clean and rebuild, but the error remains.

ERROR:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not find a part of the path 'C:\MyApp\SchoolService.MySchoolProcessor\obj\Debug\net7.0\SchoolService.MySchoolProcessor.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'.    SchoolService.MySchoolProcessor C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets  191
```

This is

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets  191

```
<GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig
  PropertyItems="@(_GeneratedEditorConfigProperty)"
  MetadataItems="@(_GeneratedEditorConfigMetadata)"
  FileName="$(GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfigFile)">
</GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig>
```

I clean and rebuild the application, the error still persists.

Comment: Can you pls just try deleting bin and obj folder of your applications

Comment: @ArvindMaurya - I tried that but still not working

Comment: Have you checked that path? At what point is there an issue?

Comment: What's your VS version? I suggest you could try to upload it to the newest version and try again. Besides, I suggest you rename the folder name to set the path less than the 260.